# Verifying multiplicative inverses of modulo n are the elements that are relatively prime to n

Tags: proof-writing, inverse

A proposition in my book states: $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} = \{a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}~|(a,n) = 1\}$ which I want to prove.

I start by defining $a$ in terms of prime factors $$a = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_i^{\alpha_i} = \prod p_i^{\alpha_i}$$ and $$n = p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}...p_i^{\beta_i} = \prod p_i^{\beta_i}$$

We have $n/ka$, $k$ is some multiple of $a$, as $\frac{ka}{n} = nq + r$

If $ka$ and $n$ have factors in common, the remainder $r$ will be $\geq $ the least common factor that isn't $1$. I don't really have any idea of how to prove this yet. Can I have some hints? I would prefer not to use a contradiction and instead show that by the process of dividing integers with common factors, a remainder that is 1 does not exist. Thank you

Comment: since $n$ and $a$ have the same prime factors, you can let $k = p_1^{\gamma_1}\ldots p_i^{\gamma_i}$ so that $ka = p_1^{\alpha_1 + \gamma_1}\ldots p_i^{\alpha_i+\gamma_i}$; then $n|ka$ when $\alpha_j+\gamma_j > \beta_j$ for all $j$. I am not sure if this helps - your statement "$n\mid ka$ ... as $\frac{ka}{n} = mq + r$" doesn't make sense to me. To say that $n\mid ka$ is to say that $r=0$.

Comment: The prime power factorization of $a$ and/or $n$ is not particularly useful in proving this result.

Comment: Also, I think you mean to say that $ka = nq + r$? Otherwise what are $q$ and $m$? I think a good way to start might be that if $a$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ then there exists some $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

Comment: There is a useful result that you might be able to use - for two integers $a$ and $b$ if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = n$, then the gcd of $a$ and $b$ must divide $n$. In particular if there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = 1$ then the gcd of $a$ and $b$ must be 1...

Comment: Let me know if you want further clarification - I can post it as an answer...

Comment: @JohnMartin: indeed, the deeper (and more important for this application) result is the converse, that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there are integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=1$.

Comment: @GregMartin I agree that the converse is deeper. Indeed. But how is that more useful here? Start by assuming $a$ is a unit. Then there exists $x$ such that $ax \equiv 1\pmod{n}$ which in turn means that $ax = ny + 1$ for some $y$, which in turn implies that the gcd is 1, which is what the OP wants to prove. The definition of a unit is not that its gcd with $n$ is 1...

Comment: @JohnMartin I see where you're going but is there a way where you don't have to assume $ax \equiv 1 (mod~n)$? I would really prefer establishing some trivial connection where by the result of there being common factors between two integers, there cannot be a remainder of 1 in their division. If this connection is made then this would easily apply to $a$ in the modulo $n$.

Comment: @JohnMartin This is why I tried to bring this to a more fundamental level, by writing the numbers in their prime factorization and observing their division. This might be what you're referring to by the linear combination? If you apply the euclidean algorithm many times you can see that the remainder is never 1 (is this true?)

Comment: I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the elements of $\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$ are the units of the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. To say that $a\in R$ is a unit is to say that there exists $x\in R$ such that $ax = 1$, but by definition of $R$ that just means that $ax\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

At this point you can write everything out in prime factors if you want, but I don't think this is more fundamental - you are relying on the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (no pun intended).

In any case, the statement $ax\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ is just saying that there exists some integer $y$ such that $ax = ny + 1$. Then you have that $ax - ny = 1$ which means that $\text{gcd}(a,n) = 1$; that's what you wanted to prove.

**EDIT**
    We need to also prove that if $(a,n) = 1$ then $a$ is a unit in $R$. But it is a Theorem (which you might try proving) that if $(a,n) = 1$ then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + ny = 1$, which implies that $ax\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ and thus $a$ is a unit in $R$.

Comment: What do you mean by $a$ is a unit?

Comment: I mean that $a$ has an inverse. That is what the collection $\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$ consists of - the invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Oh alright I see. That is quite a trivial proof! I think I could have made that connection if I wrote the expression for division (correctly) as ${ka} = nq + r$ where $r = 1$ so that $a$ and $n$ have a g.c.d of $1$ so they are relatively prime. Darn, can't believe I didn't do that. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: You have proved: $a$ is a unit implies $\gcd(a,n)=1$. There's also a converse to be proved.

Comment: Oh. right. I just proved an inclusion. Good Call. I will edit my post.

Comment: I just wanted to provide this last insight in case anyone is interested. You can also use the idea that $ax - 1 = ny$ there is no number that divides both a number and that number minus one, thus the g.c.d has to be 1.