# For which $n$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, $\bar{2}$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am looking for which $n$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, $\bar{2}$ has a multiplicative inverse.

**Attempt:** I know that I need a $\bar{k}$ such that $\bar{k}$$\bar{2}$ $= \bar{1}$. I believe that the solution should be that $n$ should be odd and that $\bar{k} = (n+1)/2$. So for instance if $n = 5$ then $\bar{k}$ = $\bar{3}$, but I don't think $\bar{3}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}/5\Bbb Z$, so I don't so why this would be right. But I do see that $\bar{3}$$\bar{2}$ $=$ $\bar{1}$. Could someone please guide me along the right path. Thanks!

Comment: You might consider this very related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761230/verifying-multiplicative-inverses-of-modulo-n-are-the-elements-that-are-relative/1761309?noredirect=1#comment3594407_1761309

Comment: You have the right answer, but are tangled up enough in the mechanics of the terminology that you aren't comfortable with it.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "I don't think $\overline{3}\in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$"?

Comment: @John like ... -3, 0, 3, 6, ... is not in ..., -5, 0, 5, 10, ...

Comment: SO from the related question if I was looking for the inverses of say 6, it would be ℤ/nℤ where n is relatively prime to 7?

Comment: The meaning of $\overline{3}\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is that you divide $3$ by $n$ and take the remainder. So $\overline{3}$ is representing the collection of all integers that have a remainder of $3$ when divided by $5$. So for instance, $13 = \overline{3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ because $13 = 5(2) + 3$ - it has a remainder of $3$ when divided by 5.

Comment: @TerryKard No, to determine for which $n$ $\overline{2}$ has a multiplicative inverse, you need to find all $n$ for which the greatest common divisor of $2$ and $n$ is 1

Comment: @JohnMartin sorry typo in the above. If I was looking for the inverse of $\bar{7}$ in Z/nZ it would be the n with gcd(7,n) = 1

Comment: @TerryKard Yes! you got it. The idea is that $\overline{7}$ has a multiplicative inverse if and only if there exists some $x$ such that $7x$ has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $n$, which is the case if and only if there exists some $y$ such that $7x = ny + 1$ which is true if and only if $(7,n) = 1$. You should make sure you know how to prove that $(7,n) = 1$ if and only if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $7x + ny = 1$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that by definition, if we have two integers $x,y$ then $\overline{x}\overline{y}\equiv 1\mod n$ iff $xy=qn+1$. Now, here presumably $n$ is odd, otherwise this is clearly impossible. But then $n+1=2j$ is even by definition of an even number. But then clearly $j$ is an inverse for $2$, so as you say $j={n+1\over 2}$ is the inverse for $2$ mod $n$.